# Prove that two bases for a vector space are equinumerous

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $B_{1},B_{2}$ are two bases for a vector space $V$, prove that there exists a bijection $f:B_{1}\rightarrow B_{2}$.

It is known to all that the statement is true for finite-dimensional vector spaces, with quite a lot of elegant proofs. I suppose there at least should be one or two similarly elegant proofs for the infinite-dimensional version, assuming that the Axiom of Choice is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, if any one basis is finite then they are both finite. So we may assume they are both infinite.

For each vector $v$ in $B_1$ there is a finite subset $S_v$ of $B_2$ that suffices to express $v$ as a linear combination. Moreover, every vector in $B_2$ must occur in one of the $S_v$, lest a proper subset of $B_2$ span $B_1$ and hence $V$. Therefore,
$$|B_2| = \left|\bigcup_{v\in B_1}S_v\right|\leq \sum_{v\in B_1}|S_v| \leq \sum_{v\in B_1}\aleph_0 = \aleph_0|B_1| = |B_1|.$$
Symmetrically, $|B_1|\leq |B_2|$.

Comment: I liked your answer from 9 years ago better. :-)